# Console won't run my Javascript code from ATOM? **Beginner

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run the code from ATOM to my console and has an error that I don't understand and won't show the function.

The code is written the exact same way as the code in my class (3rd screen).

```
[index image][1]
[JS image][2]
[Console Image][3]
[Image of instructor screen][4]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFZiL.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvoJT.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCjX6.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J26PQ.png
```

Comment: Can you show us your index.html file?

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma can you see the other images I attached?

Comment: They are formatted incorrectly but I can see them. I am asking for the source code for index.html. Could you copy and paste the code or post an image of index.html open in atom?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Coding revolution</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>





</body>



</html>

Comment: @NoahRoseLedesma the index isn't the code I'm running on the console. Sorry I'm new to coding so my terminology may be off. 

If you look at the instructors screen, he just used the JS file/screen and the console printed out the div element he made.

Answer (score 0):

You are not including your Javascript file in your html. In order for the code you have written to be executed when you open the index.html file in your browser, the javascript needs to be included. To include a javascript file add a `<script>` tag in your `<head>`.

```
<script src='/js/myJavascriptFile.js'></script>
```